# How to create a list with a specific length with different objects Python

Tags: python, list

I created a list of a specific length and noticed that all objects in the list have basically the same adress.

**Question:**
How can I create the same list with different objects?

**Example:**
bObject has a listA with 10 * objects of class A but. All those objects have the same adress (see debug screenshot below) and I would like to have 10 different objects. How do I have to change the creation of the list?

```
class geometry:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = 0
        self.end   = 0  

class AType:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 100
        self.geo = geometry()
        
class BType:
    def __init__(self):
        self.listA = [AType()] * 10
        self.d       = 0        
        
bObject = BType()
bObject.listA[0].geo.start = 0
bObject.listA[0].geo.end = 1

bObject.listA[1].geo.start = 2
bObject.listA[1].geo.end = 3
```

**debug screenshot**
[image]